# Remove numbering from `thebibliography` header

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering

So I realize I'm asking for trouble with this question because of its unknown document class, but...

I'm using my university's document class for my dissertation (a requirement), and thus it's not a standard class, such as `article` (it's `pittetd`).

I'm using the package `natbib` and the command `thebibliography` for my references, and I've been told I need to get rid of the section number (it reads "4.0 Bibliography" currently, but should read "Bibliography" only).

I've seen work-arounds that use `\chapter*` (or `\section*`) to suppress the numbering, but it doesn't work with this document class. It just ignores the asterisk, and the number remains. Two thoughts:

1) Is there a way to figure out the inner workings of the `pittetd` document class so as to find out how to suppress the numbering?

2) Should I use something other than `thebibliography` to be able to achieve this without having to worry about the document class? (Although I wouldn't want to use this option if it meant I had to go through my whole document and change the citation and reference styles.)

Comment: 1) Yes. Read it. Class files are just text files. If you have access to the class file, you already have its inner workings. On the other hand, there is no way for somebody to know *without* access to the relevant parts of the file. 2) You don't actually post what you've tried. If you are using bibtex, you have to use that command as far as I know. But you can change the kind of section it uses. But you need to provide an MWE and, if necessary, a link to the class. (That is, if you cannot reproduce the issue using a standard class.) Otherwise it is just guesses and they are likely to be poor.

Comment: Wait. You are using `thebibliography` environment *and* `natbib`? Surely that is problematic? Note that you need to use `\safebibliography` with `natbib`. See page 24-25 of the user manual for your thesis class.

Comment: This is probably my lack of true understanding of LaTeX coming through. All I do is specify `\documentclass{pittetd}` at the beginning of my file. How do I actually read it? That's what I meant by (1). As far as I know, anyone could specify that class at the beginning of their document. I have no actual text file. I don't understand your response to (2) - I stated I'm using `natbib` and `thebibliography` - nothing about `bibtex`.

Comment: @cfr I don't why using both of them would create a problem (because I don't know enough about the package and the environment). Throughout the years (literally), it's been a patchwork of various packages to try to achieve all of the formatting I need. Why do these conflict?

Comment: Yes, I used `safebib` at one point, and then changed it, but could not tell you why at this stage. I'll look at those pages...

Comment: Not `safebib`. `\safebibliography` is a command provided by your thesis class to deal with `natbib`. But it assumes you are doing the usual thing with `natbib` which is using `bibtex` to generate your references. Then you don't use `thebibliography` environment directly at all. `The thebibliography environment can be made by hand, but it is better and safer to let BibTEX do it. For this, one needs the
\bibliographystyle command already mentioned, and near the end of the document: \bibliography{mybib}` (`natbib` manual).

Comment: If you are using the class file, you can read it. Anyway, it is all at http://www.pitt.edu/~graduate/etd/latexdl.html. But whatever machine you run TeX on, you already have access to it. The manual for your thesis class seems pretty good. Impressive, actually.

Comment: Sorry - that was a mistake - I did mean `safebibliography`, yes. Trying it now.

Comment: Well it worked in that the section numbering is gone, but I have been using `\bibitem` for entries and now I think I have to change all of those...

Comment: As far as I can tell, the thesis class (at least as documented) assumes that if you are using `natbib` you'll be using `bibtex`. The other option is to dispense with `natbib`. Then `\thebibliography` with the manual entries should work fine (again, according to the manual).

Comment: Okay, no, I still don't know what to do. If I want to use `\safebibliography`, do I have to re-write all of my references *not* using `\bibitem` (I'm cringing at this prospect)? Do I have to create some separate document that I refer to in my LaTeX document? I'm very confused by the `natbib` and `bibtex` documentation.

Comment: Because even if my references using `thebibliography` environment all are working as expected, I haven't figured out how to get rid of the section number in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would is to save the definition of the environment `thebibliography` after loading `natbib` and let it be preceeded by the macro `\@safebibliography` as it normally has to be in `pittetd` class:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}{\@safebibliography\oldthebibliography}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{pittetd}

\usepackage{natbib}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}{\@safebibliography\oldthebibliography}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Last(1900)]{art1}
First Last.
\newblock A fictitious long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long journal article.
\newblock \emph{Journal of nothingness}, 2:\penalty0 1--2, 1900.

\bibitem[Writer(2000)]{boo1}
Respectable Writer.
\newblock \emph{A silly book}.
\newblock PublishCo, Somewhere, 2000.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

In this way the formatting of the bibliography is the right one.

Comment: Would it be possible to use whatever environment `\safebibliography` uses with `natbib`? Or would that amount to the same thing?

Comment: @cfr I wrote this answer thinking the OP didn't want to use `\safebibliography`. That would be the right way to go.

Comment: I think that's right. I was just thinking that the command must set up `thebibliography` environment internally so that using that definition would (hopefully) ensure that whatever fixes the class uses for `natbib` get used in the OP's thesis. But I'm not sure if this would actually give different results from your approach or not.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have a subsequent question regarding the formatting of the references: Is there a way to increase the space between lines for references that take up multiple lines (to, say, 1.5 instead of 1)? Also (I'm already regretting asking this...), hanging indents for references with more than one line (i.e. all lines after the first should be indented slightly)? These happen automatically when I use `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: @Meg I've completely rewritten the answer to meet your needs.

Comment: @cfr Without `\@safebibliography` the formatting of the bibliography was lost. I've completely rewritten the answer.

Comment: @karlkoeller You're amazing - thank you! I also added the `spacing` environment within the `thebibliography` environment to give me the 1.5 vertical spacing I needed. It's perfect now! So glad I didn't need to rewrite all of my citations... Phew. Thanks again!

Comment: @Meg I forgot about that. Anyway, if you don't need `setspace` for anything else, you can issue `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` just after `\begin{thebibliography}` to get the same result.